# what is this piece of plastic?

Tags: parts

Preparing to move, I found this together with the papers I got when I bought my bike. But what is it? Is it important?

[image: what is this?]

It is about 2cm long.

I have four of these... Maybe related to the disk brakes? I was hoping they could be pad spacers, but that might just be wishful thinking.

Comment: Even though its a perfect duplicate, I still learned something.  Welcome to the site!